# jQuery Mobile with Rails UJS to honor data-ajax="false" on links that are using data-method="delete"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-mobile

Currently i am using jquery mobile in my website. when i try to logout than data-ajax=false not working. in all other links data-ajax= false working and request dont send in ajax. but the problem occurs only on logout link. it because of data-method = delete.

```
<a class="logout-link ui-link" data-ajax="false" data-method="delete" href="<%= logout_path %>"><%= t('layouts.pull_down_menu.signout') %><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>
```

i get this output when i logout because data-ajax=false ignored by the rails and i get this output in link

> http://localhost:3000/en/main_page#/en/logout

it not redirect correctly

i tried all things from this articles and issue pages [here](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/17/jquery-mobile-and-rails-ujs-method-links/) , [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/189) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1571)

but any solution not working for me or i don't know how to apply the solution.

Thanx in advance. and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
<% link_to(logout_path, :confirm => "You sure?", :method => :delete, :class => "logout-link ui-link" "data-ajax" => "false" do %>
  <%= t('layouts.pull_down_menu.signout') %>
  <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the link is for logout the user not for delete any post and yes i already tried this but its not working   <%= link_to logout_path, method: :delete ,  data: { ajax: 'false' } ,class: "logout-link ui-link" do %>
                            <%= t('layouts.pull_down_menu.signout') %><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
                          <% end %>